# Dynamic and quitting the kernel

Tags: dynamic

No doubt `Dynamic` is one of the most interesting functions in *Mathematica*. Not rarely we observe seemingly strange behaviour, as in the following situation.

```
x=RandomReal[];
Style["Some text", 20, Background->Dynamic[Hue[x]]]
Slider[Dynamic[x]]
Dynamic[x]
```

The background colour of the text, the position of the slider and the display of `Dynamic` are all synchronized with the kernel variable `x`. Move the slider and observe the changes.

Quit the kernel, by evaluating `Quit[]` or with the evaluation menu. Then there is no kernel variable `x` any more, so  now synchronization is impossible. The display of the slider and the dynamic do not change, but the background of the text disappears.

Now click somewhere on the slider. The slider and the dynamic do not update, but the background of the text changes according to the clicked position of the slider. So not all synchronization has disappeared. What is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of `Dynamic` states that it can be used in three ways: not only directly as an expression to display, but also for example as a coordinate in a graphics primitive or an object such as a slider, or as a setting for an option. In our example we have all three ways.

With respect to quitting the kernel, the last situation turns out to be different from the two others. `LinkSnooper` shows that we if we evaluate `Dynamic[x]` or `Slider[Dynamic[x]]` and then quit the kernel, the kernel does not restart. But when we evaluate  `Style["Some text", 20, Background->Dynamic[Hue[x]]]` and quit the kernel, immediately the kernel is restarted. Let us have a closer look at the `LinkSnooper` output.

```
x=RandomReal[];
Style["Some text", 20, Background->Dynamic[Hue[x]]]
```

`LinkSnooper` shows that two dynamic objects with numbers 39935 and 40175 are created. Very likely, one of these refers to the displayed `StyleBox` and the other to the option `Background`.

```
Slider[Dynamic[x]]
```

`LinkSnooper` shows that a dynamic object with number 40257 is created.

```
Dynamic[x]
```

`LinkSnooper` shows that a dynamic object with number 40337 is created.

```
Internal`GetTrackedSymbols[]
(* Hold[{MakeBoxes,{40337},False},{x,{39935,40175,40257,40337},False}] *)
```

Therefore, all three (four) dynamic objects will be updated when the value of the kernel variable `x` changes.

```
Quit[]
```

Due to the presence of the first dynamic object, the kernel is closed and immediately a new kernel is started. `LinkSnooper` does not show any other interaction between the new kernel and the frontend, but during the startup of the new kernel something must have happened:

```
In[1]:= Internal`GetTrackedSymbols[]
Out[1]= Hold[{x,{26831,40175},False}]
```

It turns out that the object 40175 is the displayed `StyleBox`. When we closed the old kernel, immediately a new kernel was launched in which the `StyleBox` was synchronized with the (new) kernel variable `x`. When we click on the slider, the kernel variable `x` gets the value of the clicked position of the slider. The kernel variable `x` is connected to the object 40175, so the `StyleBox` will be updated, but not connected to the objects 40257 and 40337, so the slider and the dynamic will not be updated.